# FirebaseAuth signin vs linking an anonymous user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We login users anonymously in our app using FirebaseAuth, and allow them a read-only access to some of our content. At a later point of time the user can decide to login with credentials and have access to more stuff and write user specific data. The question is, do we gain anything by linking the anonymous user with the one with credentials?

Since we do not have any user specific data when the user is anonymous, it looks like a performance overhead (linking and merging seem to be slower) to link/merge as opposed to a plain sign in. Is there a downside to not linking in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You will end up with a lot of stale/abandoned anonymous user accounts and if you are saving anonymous user keyed data in your database, that will also need to be cleaned up if you choose to sign in instead of linking.

In that case (sign in instead of linking), you should consider deleting that anonymous user's data.

If you decide the linking flow, you will not run into the above.